# What is the fastest way to solve Project Euler #5?

Tags: python

I already have a way to solve Project Euler #5 (https://projecteuler.net/problem=5), but it takes forever to solve it! I've tried eliminating numbers from 1 - 10, and I'm skip-counting by 20, but still it doesn't solve fast enough. Here's my code -

```
import time
start_time = time.time()

for i in range(1,100000000000000000):
    if i % 11 == 0 and\
    i % 12 == 0 and\
    i % 13 == 0 and\
    i % 14 == 0 and\
    i % 15 == 0 and\
    i % 16 == 0 and\
    i % 17 == 0 and\
    i % 18 == 0 and\
    i % 19 == 0 and\
    i % 20 == 0:
        print(i + 19)
        break

print(time.time() - start_time," seconds taken to run program")
```

Comment: It's strange. You asked a question and posted its answer at the same time. Can I know why?

Comment: I have posted a few questions before. While asking, Stack Overflow said it's okay to ask and answer my own question. They said "Answer your own question - Share your knowledge, Q & A style" It was a checkbox I could check.

Comment: Ohh great. Good work

Answer (score 3):

You could find the LCM of the prime and composite numbers separately, and then find the LCM of their LCMs. Calculating it this way is much faster ( It gets the job done in under 2 seconds! ). So how to do this? To calculate the LCM of some numbers, we must store the greatest number in a variable and increase it by itself until it becomes divisible by the rest of the numbers. But before that, we have to make a simple function that can check and tell us when the variable is divisible by the rest of the numbers. This can be done by looping through the numbers and seeing if the remainder of `variable / number` is 0. In other words, `if number % num == 0`. In code, this would be -

```
def isDivisibleByAll(number, numbers):
    isDivisbleBy = []
    for num in numbers:
        if number % num == 0:
            isDivisbleBy.append(num)
    return isDivisbleBy == numbers
```

And the function for calculating the LCM -

```
currentNum = nums[-1]
while isDivisibleByAll(currentNum, nums) == False:
    currentNum = currentNum + nums[-1]
    print(currentNum)
```

Now, all you need to do is rinse and repeat this for the prime numbers and the LCMs of the prime and composite numbers and you're done. Full code -

```
import time

start_time = time.time()
nums = []
primeNums = []
allNums = []

def findFactors(num):
    factors = []
    for i in range(1, num + 1):
        if num % i == 0:
            if i not in factors:
                factors.append(i)
                x = int(num / i)
                factors.append(x)
            else:
                break
    return factors
 

def isDivisibleByAll(number, numbers):
    isDivisbleBy = []
    for num in numbers:
        if number % num == 0:
            isDivisbleBy.append(num)
    return isDivisbleBy == numbers



for i in range(11, 21):
    nums.append(i)

for num in nums:
    if findFactors(num) == [1, num]:
        primeNums.append(num)
        nums.remove(num)

currentNum = nums[-1]
currentPrimeNum = primeNums[-1]
while isDivisibleByAll(currentNum, nums) == False:
    currentNum = currentNum + nums[-1]
    print(currentNum)

while isDivisibleByAll(currentPrimeNum, primeNums) == False:
    currentPrimeNum = currentPrimeNum + primeNums[-1]
    print(currentPrimeNum)

allNums.append(currentNum)
allNums.append(currentPrimeNum)
currentAllNum = allNums[-1]

while isDivisibleByAll(currentAllNum, nums) == False:
    currentAllNum = currentAllNum + allNums[-1]
    print(currentAllNum)

print(currentNum, currentPrimeNum, currentAllNum)
end_time = time.time()

print("Time taken: ", end_time - start_time)
```

Answer (score 0):

What we are trying to solve here is calculating LCM(Least common multiple) for numbers 1-10 or 1-20. That we can calculate iteratively for individual number and and initial value of LCM as 1. Now the problem is how do we calculate LCM of two numbers.

From the mathematical relationship for two numbers `a` and `b`, we can say that `LCM = a*b/GCD` where GCD means `Greatest Common Divisior`.

Now the problem boils down to calculating GCD of two numbers. We can solve this problem using Euclidean algorithm.(Details here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Euclidean_algorithm).

Using this knowledge we can build a code something like this.

```
def gcd(a, b):
    big, small = (a, b) if a > b else (b, a)
    while True:
        if big % small == 0:
            return small
        else:
            rem = big % small
            big = small
            small = rem


def lcm(a, b):
    return a * b // gcd(a, b)


def solve(n):
    spn = 1  # smallest positive number
    for i in range(1, n + 1):
        spn = lcm(spn, i)
    return int(spn)


print(solve(10))  # prints 2520
print(solve(20))  # prints 232792560
```

Now it's time to see how fast our algorithm works. We can do some checking using the below code.

```
import timeit
for i in range(100, 1001, 100):
    start = timeit.default_timer()
    print(i, solve(i))
    print("time taken to solve", timeit.default_timer() - start)
```

And it prints the following.

```
100 69720375229712477164533808935312303556800
time taken to solve 6.990000000000121e-05
200 337293588832926264639465766794841407432394382785157234228847021917234018060677390066992000
time taken to solve 0.00010970000000000077
300 9014716836799586623329573573945377845159029877980505339167320652785333649613624539473353602148614605570705738411136004478202144000
time taken to solve 0.00017290000000000014
400 59667938474323557926610970384107539796305717355014061670120366929881205532187367293878763402540062687069192396177530529433679744512785143511161505144900493481243179036448000
time taken to solve 0.0002499000000000008
500 73239622318952846593863874519042298829761338251289259046349190034596307420803713394327759819891326985268312606648408875713314013313623337094312440663659803352061415560955398316253892220738945585450197206138869521568000
time taken to solve 0.00033979999999999774
600 852552424081557565184577626247749556234652180881929865734862126426950996537753180299139890983570718805268762995059679239749771514958136771134640143433321971049624604156595412965777756496065314723993568324597196421471768128860877478739231381860690643218752000
time taken to solve 0.0004402000000000017
700 3747103855339101371241072509521672143407052007320274627640914494922894046416201347161283218229033439276792258473493668540289003789030538774278518517335159636157219687521037616037905798562817324241426366431851885755580310374417332005663783078412192474544017688874378637262646845349321741208896033615680000
time taken to solve 0.0005518000000000016
800 189601219733967408707952682626742811757090989982303220357382120230749447609518005459383969469479646544380493193531218417261244352788460485076324685162362488419248140088974342925582719670808939385891431855912183140445540531533890471299438517163693242526064393743132574181989075233665242997606037318625595475469164928583247295057957435632351680000
time taken to solve 0.0006773000000000022
900 459798056995167681665827494849883896405095841898340102489813556591988443992502435128153715876000918689018697573413308698765283194390050055830472696545287570607745913821025100638868468215056942178686392864827592742130441943280664245256034413752319434508469555791283130739612138611607670673116110020222502095189837832885558059413436151262105922876437943891775053788420826419381146419568320000
time taken to solve 0.0008129999999999978
1000 7128865274665093053166384155714272920668358861885893040452001991154324087581111499476444151913871586911717817019575256512980264067621009251465871004305131072686268143200196609974862745937188343705015434452523739745298963145674982128236956232823794011068809262317708861979540791247754558049326475737829923352751796735248042463638051137034331214781746850878453485678021888075373249921995672056932029099390891687487672697950931603520000
time taken to solve 0.0009693000000000028
```

So even for calculating LCM of numbers 1-1000 the time taken is well below one millisecond.